# Where can I find documentation about the gtk+ aurora engine

Tags: gtk

I can't find any documentation about aurora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official website is [at gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Aurora+Gtk+Engine?content=56438). There are some informations, and you can download the source code.

A real documentation does not seem to exist.